# Trilateration with LMFIT Python

Tags: python, numpy, least-squares, trilateration, lmfit

I'm trying to perform Non-Linear Least-Squares Fitting LMFIT for Trilateration purposes:

- [LMFIT](http://cars9.uchicago.edu/software/python/lmfit/intro.html)
- beacons includes beacon position x,y,z
- `Parameters()` include `Xinit` location to estimate.
- `tag_distances[i]` include measurements (distance from tag to `beacon[i]`)

I get this error:

> raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
>   TypeError: Improper input: N=3 must not exceed M=1

```
import numpy as np
from math import pow
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters

beacons=np.array([[0.,0.,5.],
              [0.,15.,5.],
              [15.,0.,5.],
              [15.,15.,5.]])

tag=np.array([0,15,0])  
tag_distances=np.arange(float(beacons.shape[0]))

xinit=np.array([5.,5.,2.])

def distance (p1, p2):
    s=0
    for i in range (0,3):
    s+=(p1[i]-p2[i])**2
    return s**.5

for i in range (0,beacons.shape[0]): 
  tag_distances[i]=distance(beacons[i,:],tag)
tag_distances= tag_distances.reshape(beacons.shape[0], 1)

def residual(params, measures , beacons, eps_data):
    x=np.array([ params['x'].value,
               params['y'].value,
               params['z'].value])
    s=0
    for i in range (0,beacons.shape[0]): 
       s+=(measures[i,0]-distance(beacons[i,:],x))**2
 return s 

params = Parameters()
params.add('x', value=xinit[0])
params.add('y', value=xinit[1])
params.add('z', value=xinit[2])

eps_data=np.array([1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])

out = minimize(residual, params, args=(tag_distances, beacons, eps_data))
```

Answer (score 1):

When fitting a function to data with any least-squares algorithm (linear or non-linear), you need at least as many data points (`m`) on your curve as you have parameters in your model (`n`). If you have more parameters than points, your algorithm will not converge to a single solution (in fact there will be infinitely many equally good solutions).

The error `TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))` is raised by scipy because as your code is currently implemented, it has that `n` is larger than `m`.

lmfit's `minimize` requires that your function `residual` return an array of values and as of now, it only returns a single float. You can edit `residual` in the following away so that it returns an array of residuals:

```
def residual(params, measures , beacons, eps_data):
    x=np.array([ params['x'].value,
                 params['y'].value,
                 params['z'].value])
    s= np.empty(beacons.shape[0])   # Make s an np.array beforehand
    for i in range (0,beacons.shape[0]): 
        s[i] =(measures[i,0]-distance(beacons[i,:],x))**2 # Store each residual
    return s 

out = minimize(residual, params, args=(tag_distances, beacons, eps_data))
# Print results
print out.params['x'].value
print out.params['y'].value
print out.params['z'].value
```

Now your script will work in that it will return the parameters x,y,z which minimize the residuals returned from `residual`.

However, with the residual function you have, the parameters x,y,z which minimize this residual function will always be equal to `tag`. Thus this is not a very useful minimization procedure. I imagine you meant to write a different residual function that actually depends on `eps_data`.

Comment: Can you provide an examble on how to build this array of result? If params are x,y,z then how should I build the array of values between measuremens and the theory? I'm sure your answer is the correct but I don't know how to implement it.